# Configure git to use --recurse-submodules on cloning repository

Tags: git, recursion, command-line

How can I configure git to use `--recurse-submodules` parameter during cloning repository?

I know that I can create an alias with a different name

`proper-clone = clone --recurse-submodules`

but I want to keep using `git clone URL-to-repository`, not `git proper-clone URL-to-repository`.

I tried setting aliases

`clone-base = clone
clone = clone-base --recurse-submodules`

but it failed to change git behavior

Comment: Git aliases always depend on plumbing commands like (push, clone), therefore they cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. You can configure fetch (and pull) to recurse by default, but not this particular option for clone :(

You also can't overwrite a command using "alias", so you can't change the behaviour of "git clone" but you can, as you mentioned, do a "git myclone" alias.

The only other suggest I can think of is to alias this in bash (if you are using Linux) - you can alias "git" to use your own script called "git" and add this into your path before wherever real git is installed and you script can do the work underneath to catch any "clone" and insert the "--recurse-submodules" in that script.

Comment: `You can configure fetch (and pull) to recurse by default, but not this particular option for clone` Now I wonder whatever there is a feature request for that on git issue tracker.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny it could be, I have not looked... but there are so many parameters for the commands in git I wonder if they will bother to keep adding a configuration parameter one at a time... or if they should just support configurable defaults for all the parameters - not sure how much effort that would take... :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, there is a standard way out of this, using the configuration file for each submodule (i.e. `.gitmodules`):

```
git config submodule.<name>.fetchRecurseSubmodules 1
```

You may read more about it [on this page](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#Documentation/gitmodules.txt-submoduleltnamegtfetchRecurseSubmodules)

Comment: Still, you cannot configure it for submodules in general, right?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are not recursive (an alias is only expanded once) so this alias should work:

```
clone = clone --recurse-submodules
```

Or you can jump through shell:

```
clone = !exec /usr/lib/git-core/git-clone --recurse-submodules
```

Please note using `git-clone` directly instead of `git clone` because in that case aliases **are** recursive and you can easily create an infinite loop.